Excell Sum array by two conditions one of which is partial text string
I have a table with multiple sheets. In sheet1 I want to sum the values of particular cells from a range in sheet2 by two conditions. Cells that are to be summed are in different rows and columns.
Example:

Range for summing is in "E7:AB150"       Sum Result should be in sheet1 F37
Range for first condition is B3:B100 : Condition value is in sheet1 B37
Range for second condition is in A2:AB2 - Condition Vallue is a partial text string

Very important is that the range should remain the same if rows and columns are deleted. that is why I used offset (couldn't managed with indirect to work)
For example search result is "Sum:(C3;C35;F4:G15)
I have a working solution but I have to enter a full condition value in row 2 in order to work.
{=SUM((OFFSET('Sheet2'!$E$6;1;1;150;40))*(--('Sheet2'!$C$7:$C$152=B471))*(--(OFFSET('Sheet2'!$E$1;0;1;1;40)="TR")))
I want to replace the (--(OFFSET('Sheet2'!$E$1;0;1;1;40)="TR") part with a formula that evaluate each cell in the range of the offset and if it contains the word I am searching for to calculate as 1. in order the matrix array to work.

Solution Found!
In spreadsheet (Excel or Google Sheets), how to find the sum of multiple values with multiple rows of column headers criteria?
Now the working formula is:
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(Sheet2!$E$6;1;1;171;40))*(Sheet2!$C$7:$C$177=B219)*(LEFT(OFFSET(sheet2!$E$1;2;1;1;40);6)=$J$1&""))

Where

B219 - search value 1

$J$1 - search value 2 (Permanent cell) - could be replaced by any text string like "TURKEY"&""
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET(Sheet2!$E$6;1;1;171;40))*(Sheet2!$C$7:$C$177=B219)*(LEFT(OFFSET(sheet2!$E$1;2;1;1;40);6)="TURKEY"&""))


